# AngularJS: 'Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys."

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hauvb

The problem is that ng-repeat does not update after I push my form object into the array. I can see the content is being added to the array but ng-repeat doesn't update. I tried working with $apply but I was told I don't need that since ng-click updates the $digest for me. Any help would be appreciated to understand what I'm missing. Thanks.

```
var app = angular.module('theTasker', []);


app.controller('MyTasks', [function(){
  this.tasks = [
    {
      title: "This is the title",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      title: "This is the title",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      title: "This is the title",
      completed: false
    }
  ];

  this.myform = {
    item: "Item Title",
    completed: false
  };
  this.addtask = function(){
    this.tasks.push(this.myform);
  };
}])
```

**edit:**

the code above produces this error:

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to
>   specify unique keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while testing your code I got an error

> Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.

change your HTML ng-repeat line to look like this:

```
li(ng-repeat="task in mytasks.tasks track by $index")
```

here's an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GdH8DGzmjbbFGsUMeyyK?p=preview)

You also had a typo in the myform object, where you specified 'item' instead of 'title', so new tasks were added, but the title didn't show.

Change it to look like this:

```
this.myform = {
  title: "Item Title",
  completed: false
};
```

here's a fixed [code-pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aoEvb)

Comment: thanks - that was the problem. I hope you don't mind me extending the question, now that it's working I notice that as I add two or three various items that they all update now to the value of the most recent entry. Essentially I am just replicating the object and not creating new instances of the object. I'm not sure where to implement some kind of "new" constructor in this situation. Where would I do that?

Comment: You need to prepare an object, with a the value from the input, and push it on the button click. just like now, only with real data.

Answer (score 0):

Your array needs to be on a scope. Trythis ensuring ng-repeat is repeats over "tasks":

```
app.controller('MyTasks', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.tasks = [
    {
      title: "This is the title",
      completed: false
    },
    {
      title: "This is the title",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      title: "This is the title",
      completed: false
    }
  ];

  this.myform = {
    item: "Item Title",
    completed: false
  };
  this.addtask = function(){
    $scope.tasks.push(this.myform);
  };
}])
```

Comment: it's scoped to the controller via 'controller as' syntax like in the codepen example. Can it not work that way to? The initial ng-repeat sees it just fine and the array updates fine, it's just ng-repeat doesn't update.

Comment: Values that are watched in order to respond to change need to be on a scope. I think what you've done is give the controller object some extra properties that ng-repeat is unable to "watch" for changes.